# How do I declare a row value in a Gridview using the RowDeleting Method?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with a path in it ("FullPath"). What I want to do is when the row is being deleted. I want the file to also be deleted on the Server, so I need to declare the path so I can delete it but I can't figure out how to....

I have tried:

```
Protected Sub gvFileList_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)

    Dim id As Integer = gvFileList.SelectedRow.Cells("FullPath").Text
    Dim strFolderName = gvFileList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("FullPath")
    Console.WriteLine(strFolderName)

End Sub
```

Here is the Gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvFileList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDeleting="gvFileList_RowDeleting" Width="100%" Caption="File List" CaptionAlign="Left" CssClass="gvFileList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvFileList_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="10" DataKeyNames="ID">
     <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Delete" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="FullPath" HeaderText="File Path" SortExpression="FileName" Visible="true"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="CreationTime" HeaderText="CreationTime" SortExpression="CreationTime" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="LastWrittenTime" HeaderText="LastWrittenTime" SortExpression="LastWrittenTime" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="LastAccessed" HeaderText="LastAccessed" SortExpression="LastAccessed" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="SubDirectoryCategory" HeaderText="SubDirectoryCategory" SortExpression="SubDirectoryCategory"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractNumber" HeaderText="ContractNumber" SortExpression="ContractNumber"></asp:BoundField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>




Protected Sub gvFileList_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)

    Dim id As Integer = gvFileList.SelectedRow.Cells("FullPath").Text
    Dim strFolderName = gvFileList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("FullPath")
    Console.WriteLine(strFolderName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just keep in mind that there are two types of file paths you deal with.

A URL or web based file path.

A internal standard windows file name.

So, in the web site, in markup and in a page, then you can say have a valid path to the file like this:

```
 www.mywebsite.com/Myfiles/fun.pdf
```

Or even say:

```
"~/MyFiles/fun.pdf"
```

If that control is a server side control (you can't use "~/" in mark up unless that expression is generated by server side control).

So, while such "URL" paths will map rather nice into your existing folders on the web site, for code behind?

Code behind ALWAYS will continue to use a standard FULL windows path name.

Now, it not clear why your code is "flipping" from using the .cells() collection, and that of using find control.

You ONLY use find control for templated columns, but for any data fields, then you use the .cells collection.

So, is full path just the path, or is it full path + file name?

And is full path a web based url, or a full internal standard windows file path name?

So, assuming the URL or file path you have is web based?

Then your code to delete the file can be this:

```
   Dim strFolder As String = gvFileList.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
   Dim strFile As String = gvFileList.SelectedRow.Cells(5).Text

   Dim strURLFile = strFolder & "/" & strFile

   Dim strWindowsFile = Server.MapPath(strURLFile)

   If File.Exists(strWindowsFile) Then
       File.Delete(strWindowsFile)

   End If
```

So, keep in mind that the .cells collection DOES NOT allow use of a name, it is a zero based array, starting at 0. So, (unfortunately) you have to pull values from the grid row by using the column number, and use of the column name does not work.

So, I guessed, and folder value looks to be the 2nd column, so 1.

And then file name is in the 6th column, so 5.

so, you get the folder, the file name, and THEN convert from a valid web based URL to a internal windows file name.

In above code, I don't know if full path includes the trailing "/". In fact, I don't know if that full path is a URL (web path) or a internal windows path name.

So, keep in mind the difference between URL's to be used in the web page and markup, and that of code behind.

Code behind ALWAYS will use and require a full valid good old windows path name. You thus can't use code behind to read or use or enjoy a file name based on valid web URL path names.